# Renaming files with string extracted from filename

Tags: powershell

I have the following code in powershell script:

```
#Call Bluezone to do file transfer
#start-process "\\fhnsrv01\home\aborgetti\Documentation\Projects\Automation\OpenBZ.bat"
#Variable Declarations
$a = Get-Date
$b = $a.ToString('MMddyy')
$source = "\\fhnsrv01\home\aborgetti\Documentation\Stage\"
$dest = "\\fhnsrv01\home\aborgetti\Documentation\Stage\orig"
#Find all the files that have EDIPROD extension and proceed to process them
#First copy the original file to the orig folder before any manipulation takes place
Copy-item $source\*.EDIPROD $dest
# Now we must rename the items that are in the table
Switch(GCI \\fhnsrv01\home\aborgetti\Documentation\Stage\*.EDIPROD){
    {(GC $_|Select -first 1).substring(176) -match "^834"}{$_ | Rename-Item -NewName {"834Dailyin$b"};Continue}
    {(GC $_|Select -first 1).substring(176) -match "^820"}{$_ | Rename-Item -NewName {"820Dailyin$b"};Continue}
}
```

The part I'm concerned with is here:

```
Switch(GCI \\fhnsrv01\home\aborgetti\Documentation\Stage\*.EDIPROD){
    {(GC $_|Select -first 1).substring(176) -match "^834"}{$_ | Rename-Item -NewName {"834Dailyin$b"};Continue}
    {(GC $_|Select -first 1).substring(176) -match "^820"}{$_ | Rename-Item -NewName {"820Dailyin$b"};Continue}
}
```

I am appending the variable `$b` at the end of the filename. this holds the date. However, the real date I'm interested in is in the filename itself, and that looks something like this:

`AIDOCCAI.D051414.T025848.MO.EDIPROD`

I need to have powershell extract the `D051414` to get the date `051414` and append that to the end of the file.

Otherwise I repeatedly get this error: Cannot rename-item because item already exists.

Can anyone help with this? I would like to keep original structure of switch statement as that works very well. Having the date on there however, does not. But the file only comes once a day, so every file will have a different date and that would work, just need some help on how to get there.

UPDATE

```
Switch(GCI \\fhnsrv01\home\aborgetti\Documentation\Stage\*.EDIPROD){
    {(GC $_|Select -first 1).substring(176) -match "^834"}{$_ | {$_ | ?{$_.Name -match "^.+?\.D(\d{6}).*"} | Rename-Item -NewName {"834Dailyin$($Matches[1])"}}
    {(GC $_|Select -first 1).substring(176) -match "^820"}{$_ | {$_ | ?{$_.Name -match "^.+?\.D(\d{6}).*"} | Rename-Item -NewName {"820Dailyin$($Matches[1])"}}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the 834 rename line to replace the switch's scripteblock to read:

```
{$_ | ?{$_.Name -match "^.+?\.D(\d{6}).*"} | Rename-Item -NewName {"834Dailyin$($Matches[1]).txt"};Continue}
```

Comment: Says expressions are only allowed at beginning of pipeline

Comment: Give the original file named AIDOCCAI.D051414.T025848.MO.EDIPROD what should it look like if it is an 834 file, and what should it look like if it is an 820 file?

Comment: Ah excellent question. There are actually NO identifying characteristics via the filename. It's a mish mash of numbers in the x.x.T######.MO.EDIPROD. The only way to tell is from the first line in the file....Does this help?

Comment: That doesn't tell me what that specific file name would be after the rename. Given that file name, would it be `AIDOCCAI.D051414.T025848.MO.EDIPROD.843Dailyin051414`? Or `AIDOCCAI.D051414.T025848.MO.834Dailyin051414`? If it were an 820 file, would it be named the same except with 820 in place of 834?

Comment: correct...sorry I misunderstood. it's actually not keeping the original filename at all. It would just be 834dailyin051414.txt or 820051414.txt

Comment: Ok, updated answer just a little. First make sure that what it is trying to name the file to does not already exist. Then try with that and see if you still get the same issue.

Comment: `Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline.
At H:\Documentation\Projects\Automation\NameChanger.ps1:13 char:173
+     {(GC $_|Select -first 1).substring(176) -match "^834"}{$_ | {$_ | ?{$_.Name -match "^.+?\.D(\d{6}).*"} | Rename-I
tem -NewName {"834Dailyin$($Matches[1]).txt"};Continue} <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpressionsMustBeFirstInPipeline
`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/53831/discussion-between-hituptony-and-themadtechnician)